# Generate filter criteria based on multiple field combinations

Tags: c#

The `PrepareConditions` method in the `FeeTypeQueryService` class prepares the conditions based on the `searchConditions` parameter and returns as an `object`. `searchConditions` can only have 3 combinations, such as:

1. Filter by `TenantId`, `FeeTypeId`
2. Filter by `TenantId`, `FeeTypeName`
3. Filter by `TenantId`, `FeeTypeId`, `FeeTypeName`

**Note:** The `TenantId` is mandatory for all the filter criterias.

**Question**: Is there a better way to write the `PrepareConditions` method so that it doesn't become complicated with a long list of conditional statements? When I start to have more properties in the `FeeTypeSearchModel` class, this may get dirty - I think.

Sample code:

**FeeTypeQueryService.cs**

```
public sealed class FeeTypeQueryService
{
    private object PrepareConditions(FeeTypeSearchModel searchConditions)
    {
        object conditions = null;

        if (searchConditions.FeeTypeId.HasValue && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchConditions.FeeTypeName))
        {
            conditions = new { TenantId, FeeTypeId = searchConditions.FeeTypeId.Value };
            return conditions;
        }

        if (!searchConditions.FeeTypeId.HasValue && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchConditions.FeeTypeName))
        {
            conditions = new { TenantId, searchConditions.FeeTypeName };
            return conditions;
        }

        if (searchConditions.FeeTypeId.HasValue && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchConditions.FeeTypeName))
        {
            conditions = new { TenantId, FeeTypeId = searchConditions.FeeTypeId.Value, searchConditions.FeeTypeName };
            return conditions;
        }

        conditions = new { TenantId };
        return conditions;
    }
}
```

**FeeTypeSearchModel.cs**

```
public sealed class FeeTypeSearchModel
{
    public int? FeeTypeId { get; set; }
    public string FeeTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I find there is not enough information for a review. What are you building this for? Are you using this with Dapper, Entity Framework, WebAPI, linq to objects or anything else? What is the purpose of this code? What are you going to filter? Why should you have more properties?

Answer (score 4):

Usually I tell at code reviews that saving a level of indentation is a good thing, but in the case of your code I wondered why you placed three times the same condition because I had a hard time to notice the `!`'s so I would suggest to take a different route, otherwise you will be confused in half a year as well.

I would use a `if..else if´ like so

```
if (searchConditions.FeeTypeId.HasValue)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchConditions.FeeTypeName))
    {
        return new { TenantId, FeeTypeId = searchConditions.FeeTypeId.Value };
    }
    return new { TenantId, FeeTypeId = searchConditions.FeeTypeId.Value, searchConditions.FeeTypeName };
}
else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchConditions.FeeTypeName))
{
    return new { TenantId };    
}

return new { TenantId, searchConditions.FeeTypeName };
```

Answer (score 3):

There are various techniques you may use, for example Reflection or `Expression` but in general what I'd do is to move this logic into the model. If you split this logic into `FeeTypeQueryService` and in `FeeTypeSearchModel` then each time you want to add a new condition you will have to change two classes (with higher chances to *forget* something).

More than that this code is prolix and error-prone. When you add 3 or 4 more conditions you will have a wall of repetitive, verbose and prolix code.

First of all, why do you  need to *flat* your conditions in the model?

```
public abstract class SearchModel { }

public sealed class ByFeeTypeSearchModel: SearchModel 
{
    public int FeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Your search parameters will simply be a `IEnumerable<SearchModel>`. If, to simplify UI logic, you want to keep them all in-place using null values then add a `SearchModel.IsPresent` property. A proof of concept:

```
public abstract class SearchModel
{ 
    public abstract bool IsPresent { get; }

    public abstract void Apply(dynamic criteria);
}

public sealed class ByFeeTypeSearchModel : SearchModel
{
    public int? FeeId { get; set; }

    public override IsPresent => FeeId.HasValue;

    public override Apply(dynamic searchCriteria)
    {
        Debug.Assert(IsPresent);

        searchCriteria.FeeId = FeeId.Value;
    }
}
```

In this example I'm using `dynamic` instead of an anonymous type but I'd consider also a dictionary (it depends how you will consume this object).

Your function will then be pretty simple:

```
private object PrepareConditions(IEnumerable<SearchModel> searchConditions)
{
    var conditions = new ExpandoObject();
    conditions.TenantId = TenantId;

    foreach (var searchCondition in searchConditions.Where(x => x.IsPresent))
        searchCondition.Apply(conditions);

    return conditions;
}
```

---

Don't you want to have separate classes for each group of search fields? Decorate your model with attributes or simply go by convention, pseudo-code:

```
private object PrepareConditions(object searchConditions)
{
    var conditions = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
    conditions.Add(nameof(TenantId), TenantId);

    foreach (var property in searchConditions.GetProperties())
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(searchConditions);
        if (IsNull(value))
            continue;

        conditions.Add(property.PropertyName, value);
    }

    return conditions;
}
```

If you use `conditions` with Dapper, for example, you may need to manually add support for dynamic objects but definitely it is worth of the small effort.

Comment: You are so right, am using Dapper as ORM. But the trick would be to use "=", ">", etc..

Comment: If I remember correctly (I didn't use dapper often) there is an extension for that, field comes as `Expression` and operator is an `enum`

Comment: I think you are talking about `https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions`, which has a clean implementation for `predicates`.

Comment: Can you please clarify or elaborate a bit further, what do you mean by `manually add support for dynamic objects` in your last paragraph?

Comment: Yes, maybe that one. Last time I needed something like this dapper didn't support dynamic objects and I had to add that. On that time dapper code really needed...a Code Review but maybe now it's better. You just need to go through "plain" properties and dynamically added ones (generating accessors for them, a look to C# generated IL will help you a lot)